# Delphi 2010 compiling without errors , GUI not showing can you please read below?

Tags: forms, delphi, compilation

I writed a program and has been working on it for days now. Suddenly everytime i try to compile delphi compiles without errors and then runs asif the program is opened. There is No GUI anymore. Now i have to enter a on create event .show   :

```
procedure TfrmMAINlogin.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
           frmMAINlogin.Show;
end;
```

The form shows now but I'm unable to use it , windows labels it as not responding;

Comment: -1 for complete absence of useful information

Comment: There is no more information to it @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Comment out the frmMAINlogin.Show; line.  Does it work then?

Comment: @MartynA Nope I added it to make it show but delphi doesn't want to show anything without it. Is there anyway to make delphi show the forms like it should do Standardly.

Comment: Of course there is more information. Clearly the code in the question makes no sense. You don't call Show there. But there is more. You must remove all the code in the question because it is bogus. And then you need to work out what the question is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan :| .... Serious , I know you don't call it there that is the only way it will start showing again. Its not the codes problem with it or without it it doesn't work on any program i've written. The only way it shows is with frmMAINlogin.Show;

Comment: That code is wrong. You must remove it. The main form will be shown automatically provided you didn't make it invisible. The problem is not in the code you show because it is wrong and must be removed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , That is the problem its not Automatically showing the form. After i realised that it is not showing automatically i added that . :)

Comment: Remove that code and let's try to find the real problem

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks a lot for your help , its Fixed. Hahaha it is embarrassing ... frmMAINlogin.visible := false ; it was not visible in the object inspector. Is it possible that i pressed a shortcut to make it not visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, the reason why your form was not showing, is that you had made it invisible by setting `Visible` to `False`.

Reverse that change, and remove the code in the question. You do not need to, and indeed should not, explicitly show the main form.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was a rookie error!!!